# Batch commands working after copying the contents of source text file to another

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have an application which exports some data and stores them in a text file (ex.: `abc.txt`).
I want to remove quotes from that text file.
So I wrote a batch file for that.
But there is no output in my destination file.

But when I copy the contents of `abc.txt` to `def.txt` and run the batch file on this new file (`def.txt`) then it is working fine.

My Code is:

```
@echo off & setlocal

set "textfile=%1"
set "newfile=%2"

set "CS1=""
set "CR1="

(for /f "delims=" %%i in (%textfile%) do (
    set "line=%%i"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "line=!line:%CS1%=%CR1%!"
    echo(!line!
    endlocal
))>"%newfile%"
```

Comment: Post some code. How do you expect us to help you with your code without  posting ist?

Comment: The code looks a bit unconventional. Since the batch language is mostly undocumented it's difficult to say what should work or not. But the problem of one file not working, when it has apparently the same context as another working file, may just be a text encoding issue.

Comment: I have posted the code.

Comment: I guess the problem could be how quotation marks are placed around the file names: 1. you should change your `%1`, `%2` expansions to `%~1` and `%~2` in order to remove potential surrounding `""`; 2. you should change your `for /f` command line to `for /f "usebackq delims=" %%i in ("%textfile%") do (...)`; otherwise you might run into trouble when a provided file path containes white-spaces... in general, regard that `for /f` skips all lines of the text file which are empty or start with `;`; if you do not want that, please describe in your post...

Comment: I was able to generate the same characteristic by saving `abc.txt` as a unicode file and "copying" it to `def.txt` using `more`. Perhaps if you were to explain what method you used to copy the file it would become more obvious.

Comment: Problem solved i had to convert file from ASCII to Unicode using TYPE command

Answer (score 0):

Your code is quite confusing. For me this works:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "textfile=%1"
set "newfile=%2"

for /f "delims=" %%i in (%textfile%) do (
    set "line=%%i"
    set "line=!line:"=!"
    echo !line!>>%newfile%
)
```

Comment: your code carries the same issue I described in the [comment above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35865519/batch-commands-working-after-copying-the-contents-of-source-text-file-to-another#comment59397016_35865519); and you introduced two new problems: 1. delayed expansion is always on, which causes problems with exclamation marks `!` during expansion of `%%i`; 2. you have multiple file accesses ahere you append line per line, which reduces overall performance and requires the file not to exist before running this script;

Comment: I have tried this code still it is working for only one file ie..def.txt

Answer (score 0):

Convert the file from UNICODE to ASCII format using TYPE command